# Difference between cc and cc -c when compiling a C program

Tags: c, cc

I am new to C language and I need to know what is the difference between cc filename.c and cc -c filename.c when compiling a C source code.  I know that cc -c command creates an object module,  if so how to convert that object module into a executable file.

Comment: Wait, is this asking how to compile object files? It sounds like you already know what the difference between `cc` and `cc -c` is.

Comment: Why we need to create an object file?  Why don't we directly create the executable  file?

Comment: @buddhi-weerasinghe In larger applications you normally have many modules, like foo.c, bar.c and main.c. In this case it's more convenient to compile each one with -c and then link the objects at the end to produce the executable.

Answer (score 2):

To create an executable file from object modules, you need to link them using `cc` or `ld` or some other linker as follows

```
 cc a.o b.o c.o -o final.bin
```

You can also mention the libraries which you want to link here.

It will generate executable if any of these have atmost one entry point (main function).